# Как правильно распрасить JSON?

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api, json.net

Добрый вечер.

Отправляю [данный](https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1,2,1&fields=photo_50) GET-запрос

Классы для парсинга.

```
public class USERSresponse
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string secondname { get; set; } 
    public string photourl { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public  USERSresponse[] response { get; set; }
}
```

Метод парсинга

```
private data GetJson (string url)
{
    string StreamStr = "";
    using(StreamReader srr=new StreamReader(Get(url)))
    {
        StreamStr = srr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<data>(StreamStr);

    return data;
 }
```

В строку `StreamStr` верно записывается JSON-объект(поток получаем верно).
По итогу имеем вот такую `data`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем ошибка, пожалуйста, спасибо заранее.

Comment: А json это принципиально? Есть родной XMLDocument и VK прекрасно в нем выдает ответы, если в конце названия метода дописывать .xml.

Comment: Нет не принципиально,про xml в курсе,спасибо, просто был выбран JSON для работы.Xml тоже парсить нужно, в любом случае))

Comment: Как мне показалось с XML проще работать. Один лишь выбор по SelectNodes(XPath) как упрощает работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы неверно определили классы-модели для дальнейшей десериализации с помощью метода `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`. Структура должна быть такой, и менять имена свойств *не нужно*, иначе снова всё сломается.

```
public class User
{
    public int Uid { get; set; }
    public string First_name { get; set; }
    public string Last_name { get; set; }
    public string Photo_50 { get; set; }
    public int? Hidden { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public User[] Response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Имена свойств можно использовать любые, более соответствующие принятому в C# неймингу. А отобразить их на имена в json можно с помощью атрибута `JsonProperty`.